# Object[] elementData,int size

Tags: java

В реализации класса ArrayList есть следующие поля:Object[] elementData,int size.Объясните,зачем хранить отдельно size,если можно взять elementData.lenght?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поле size хранит количество элементов уже находящихся в массиве, в то время как elementData.length вернет всего-лишь размер массива elementData